# Why is getline taking one extra line?

Tags: c++, getline

why the for loop execute m-1 times instead of m.
I have used `getline()` to enter string instead of `cin>>`.
Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n;
    int m;
    int a;

    cin >> n >> m;

    int arr[10000];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    char s[200];

    ostream_iterator<int> screen(cout," ");

    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        cin.getline(s,20);
        int p = s[2]-48;
        cout << p << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After last `cin>>arr[i]`, there is a newline remaining in the stream. So the new line will be assigned to `s` at the first iteration in the for loop without your input, so it looks like the for loop only iterates `m-1` times. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction) for the explanation and solution.

Answer (score 2):

Because this:

```
cin>>n>>m;
```

Has not read the end of line character from the first line.

Thus the first time through the loop.

```
cin.getline(s,20);
```

Will read an empty line.

PS. Prefer to use the string reading version of `getline()`. That way you guarantee that you can always read a full line.